# Object spawn delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this spawning script in my game and you can buy more spawners from a shop.
I would like to have the spawn delay be like if the delay is 1, spawning is slow and if it's 20 then the spawning would be faster. Is this even possible? Thanks!

```
    IEnumerator PigSpawner (float spawnInterval, GameObject PigToSpawn) {
    GameObject InstatiatedObject = Instantiate(PigToSpawn, new Vector3(Random.Range(bottomLeftWorld.x, topRightWorld.x), Random.Range(bottomLeftWorld.y, topRightWorld.y), 0), Quaternion.identity, Parent);
    InstatiatedObject.GetComponent<Destroy>().enabled = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnInterval);
    StartCoroutine (PigSpawner (spawnInterval, PigToSpawn));
}
```

Comment: Of course it’s possible.

Comment: `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1 / spawnInterval);`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

```
IEnumerator PigSpawner(float spawnInterval, GameObject PigToSpawn) 
{
    while(true)
    {
        GameObject InstatiatedObject = Instantiate(PigToSpawn, new Vector3(Random.Range(bottomLeftWorld.x, topRightWorld.x), Random.Range(bottomLeftWorld.y, topRightWorld.y), 0), Quaternion.identity, Parent);
        InstatiatedObject.GetComponent<Destroy>().enabled = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnInterval);
    }
}
```

Then you would want to call this with an [inverse lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.InverseLerp.html) to get that behaviour, like so

```
StartSpawner()
{
    var spawnIntervalMagnitude = Mathf.InverseLerp(_minumumSpawnTimeValue, _maximumSpawnTimeValue, _spawnDelay); 
    var spawnInterval = _defaultSpawnInterval * spawnIntervalMagnitude;

    StartCoroutine(PigSpawner(spawnInterval, _pigToSpawn));
}
```

In this example `_minumumSpawnTimeValue` might be `1` and `_maximumSpawnTimeValue` might be `20`. You will need a default spawn time, and then any value you set between 1, and 20 will be linearly interpolated between those values to give a bigger/smaller delay :-)

Comment: For some reason when i buy the speed up upgrade it just slows down.
code: https://pastebin.com/j7v242z6

Comment: @valzzu I'm afraid I can't really understand your problem from this comment alone. Could you open a new question and explain what you mean in more detail? I'll come to answer it there :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// spawner script

public int spawnInterval = 1;
public GameObject enemy;

void Start()
{
    while(true)
    {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnInterval);
         Instantiate(enemy, transform.position, Quaternion.normalized);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to a comment, I just realized that you're looking for a negative-feedback system where higher numbers make it faster. That can be done by just waiting `1/spawninterval` instead of `spawninterval`. I've done that below, and replaced spawninterval with spawnspeed.

```
// spawner script

public int spawnSpeed = 1;
public GameObject enemy;

void Start()
{
    while(true)
    {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(1 / spawnSpeed);
         Instantiate(enemy, transform.position, Quaternion.normalized);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants something like this `if the delay is 1, spawning is slow and if it's 20 then the spawning would be faster`

Comment: Thanks. I've eddited the answer. @DigvijaysinhGohil

Comment: Just keep in mind this solution will not make the spawn delay scale linearly with the input value, rather hyperbolically, so the spawn time will quickly decrease then level out fast. Changing from 1 to 2 will be a 50% speed increase but 19 to 20 will be less than 1%

Comment: @Jay that could be fixed by changing (1 / spawnSpeed) to (1 / (spawnSpeed * 3)), or by making it a float instead of an int.

Comment: @personthehuman unfortunately, while that could mitigate it slightly, neither of those would fix the problem (it would have to be a float to work at all). The function you gave is hyperbolic and scaling it wouldn't change that, you would need to use a linear function (such as an inverse linear interpolation) for the output to scale linearly