# Object spwaning with inverselerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this spawning code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71701808/object-spawn-delay). it's supposed to work like the bigger the delay the faster it spawns pigs, but the problem is that when I buy an upgrade that speeds up pig spawning it just slows down the spawning.

Here's a video [youtube](https://youtu.be/Zahiz40kMSM)

```
void StartSpawner(string pigName)
{
    _spawnDelay = 0f;
    switch (pigName)
    {
        case "Muddy Pig":
            _spawnDelay = MuddyPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
        case "Devil Pig":
            _spawnDelay = DevilPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
        case "Nerd Pig":
            _spawnDelay = NerdPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
        case "Angel Pig":
            _spawnDelay = AngelPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
        case "Player Pig":
            _spawnDelay = PlayerPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
        case "Hentai Pig":
            _spawnDelay = HentaiPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < pigInfos.Count; i++)
    {
        if (pigInfos[i].PigName == pigName)
        {
            _PigSpawnRate = pigInfos[i].PigSpawnRate;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < PigObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (PigObjects[i].name == pigName)
        {
            PigToSpawn = PigObjects[i];
        }
    }
    _spawnDelay += _PigSpawnRate;

    spawnIntervalMagnitude = Mathf.InverseLerp(_minumumSpawnTimeValue, _maximumSpawnTimeValue, _spawnDelay);
    spawnInterval = _defaultSpawnInterval * spawnIntervalMagnitude;

    StartCoroutine(PigSpawner(spawnInterval, PigToSpawn));
}

IEnumerator PigSpawner(float spawnInterval, GameObject PigToSpawn)
{
    GameObject InstatiatedObject = Instantiate(PigToSpawn, new Vector3(Random.Range(bottomLeftWorld.x, topRightWorld.x), Random.Range(bottomLeftWorld.y, topRightWorld.y), 0), Quaternion.identity, Parent);
    InstatiatedObject.GetComponent<Destroy>().enabled = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnInterval);
    StartSpawner(PigToSpawn.name);
}
```

Comment: To delay (verb) means to make someone or something late or slow. A delay (noun) is a period of time by which something is late or postponed. 
If you want the spawning to be faster when people buy upgrades, what you want is for upgrades to make the delay between spawns smaller, not bigger.

Comment: I decided to go with that route and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inverse the scaling just replace "Mathf.InverseLerp" with "Mathf.Lerp", like bellow.

What's happening is that you're increasing the value of _spawnDelay right here:

```
_spawnDelay += _PigSpawnRate;
```

But then you're using inverse lerp for the interval magnitude, this means that on:

```
spawnIntervalMagnitude = Mathf.InverseLerp(_minumumSpawnTimeValue, _maximumSpawnTimeValue, _spawnDelay);
```

the higher _spawnDelay is the closer the magnitude gets to _minumumSpawnTimeValue.

```
void StartSpawner(string pigName)
{
    _spawnDelay = 0f;
    switch (pigName)
    {
        case "Muddy Pig":
            _spawnDelay = MuddyPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
        case "Devil Pig":
            _spawnDelay = DevilPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
        case "Nerd Pig":
            _spawnDelay = NerdPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
        case "Angel Pig":
            _spawnDelay = AngelPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
        case "Player Pig":
            _spawnDelay = PlayerPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
        case "Hentai Pig":
            _spawnDelay = HentaiPigSpawnMultiplier;
            break;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < pigInfos.Count; i++)
    {
        if (pigInfos[i].PigName == pigName)
        {
            _PigSpawnRate = pigInfos[i].PigSpawnRate;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < PigObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (PigObjects[i].name == pigName)
        {
            PigToSpawn = PigObjects[i];
        }
    }
    _spawnDelay += _PigSpawnRate;

    spawnIntervalMagnitude = Mathf.InverseLerp(_minumumSpawnTimeValue, _maximumSpawnTimeValue, _spawnDelay);
    spawnInterval = _defaultSpawnInterval * spawnIntervalMagnitude;

    StartCoroutine(PigSpawner(spawnInterval, PigToSpawn));
}

IEnumerator PigSpawner(float spawnInterval, GameObject PigToSpawn)
{
    GameObject InstatiatedObject = Instantiate(PigToSpawn, new Vector3(Random.Range(bottomLeftWorld.x, topRightWorld.x), Random.Range(bottomLeftWorld.y, topRightWorld.y), 0), Quaternion.identity, Parent);
    InstatiatedObject.GetComponent<Destroy>().enabled = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnInterval);
    StartSpawner(PigToSpawn.name);
}
```